# Paypal Recurring Payments using express checkout

Tags: paypal

We want to use Paypal Recurring payments using express checkout. We need to cater to the described usecase

My existing package is $49/month and the next available package is $99/month. When user upgrades the package can I change their billing amount to $99/month using express checkout?

API documentation says "You can increase the profile amount by only 20% in each 180-day interval after you create the profile." Is there any workaround for this?

Looking forward to your reply.

Regards,
Richa Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way around that limitation unless you're using Payments Pro.  With Pro profiles there is no limit.

With Express Checkout the only way to handle this sort of thing is to kill their existing profile and create a new one for them.

You can cancel the existing profile using [ManageRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/managerecurringpaymentsprofilestatus-api-operation-nvp) and then walk the user through the process of creating a new profile accordingly.

It's not ideal, but that's the only way to do it with Express Checkout.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Will Paypal Pro also handle this limitation - "For recurring payments with the Express Checkout API, PayPal does not allow certain updates, such as billing amount, within 3 days of the scheduled billing date."

Comment: Are you seeing that in the documentation somewhere?  I'm pretty sure I've updated prices on profiles within 3 days and it worked just fine, but I'd have to test specifically to confirm.

Comment: Yes, it is in the documentation. I am waiting on your confirmation.